# Comparing date in Access SQL query

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm having trouble with Access sql query. Im new to this so bieng a rookie its difficult to figure out the syntax. below is my query.

```
SELECT *
FROM BookingMaster WHERE JourneyDate = #01/08/2012#;
```

below is the respective table data:

```
BookingID   BookingDate    JourneyDate   CustomerName   TelephoneNo  Address
5            01-08-2012     01-08-2012         roshan         78889     hjgj
```

the above query listed returns 0 results even though data exist for 01/08/2012 journey date.

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unless you are working in a US locale, it is best to use a year, month, day format for dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM BookingMaster where JourneyDate = #2012/08/01#;
```

Comment: if i have to compare..two date..with following format what i have to do..dd/mm/yyyy is there any format function...?

Comment: Yes, there is. Format(ADate,"yyyy/mm/dd") for one (there are others) will return a string. It may not be available outside of Access. How you use dates with MS Access depends a lot on where you are working, the query design screen, VBA, outside of Access, etc.

Answer (score 4):

try this..

```
SELECT * FROM BookingMaster where (JourneyDate >= #01/08/2012#) and (JourneyDate < #01/09/2012#);
```