# How to delete error [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'date=19apr2015.'

Tags: java, ms-access, odbc

Please tell me how to solve the error from the code. I want to get the details from the ms access table. I have used data and description as columns. date is the primary key in ms access. so please let me help me with reading the data from ms access table.

---

```
try{   
    connect();     
    stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    String sql, ks = " ";
    ks = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter the date of which you want to read");      
    String jk = " where date=" + ks; 


    sql = "SELECT [date],[description]  FROM  Table2" + jk;
    System.out.println("1");
    rs = ((java.sql.Statement) stmt).executeQuery(sql);

    if(rs.next())
    {
        String date1="hello",description1="hii";
        date1 = rs.getString("date");
        description1=rs.getString("description");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Date:"+date1+"\n"+description1);
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry the record does not exist");
        try
        {
            close();
        }
        catch(Exception ea)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:"+ea.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ew)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to fetch Data");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ew.getMessage());
    System.out.println(""+ew);
}
```

---

Thanks

Comment: Fix your formatting and I'll tell you the reason for your error! ;)

Comment: whats the probem with the formatting it appears good I guess.

Comment: You are welcome. Formatting is a common mistake :)

Comment: @KarrthikReddyChinasani Your error has nothing to do with java. There is a syntax error in the where clause of your SQL query. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814853/comparing-date-in-access-sql-query or http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tips-for-working-with-dates-in-microsoft-access/ to see how to use dates in MS Access.

Comment: i have used string for date.I mean string has been used to store the data for example like 19apr2015. i have used long text for date in the access table

Comment: Similar problem. Strings need to be quoted ('). So it should be: `... where date='19apr2015'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says that there is a syntax error in your SQL query. In your example, it seems to be:

```
SELECT [date],[description] FROM Table2  where date=19apr2015.
```

This is wrong as the date (`19apr2015`) does not have the correct format.

A correct SQL query would be:

```
SELECT [date],[description] FROM Table2  where date=#4/19/2015#
```

So you will have to parse the user input and convert it into the correct form, or request the user to enter the date in the correct form.

**SQL injection**

In both cases it is adviced to use a `PreparedStatement` with the date as parameter instead of putting together the SQL statement using string concatenation, as the latter is dangerous because of an evil thing called [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)! For example, imagine, the user wants to do any harm and instead of entering a valid date, he/she enters

```
#1/1/2000#; DELETE * FROM Table2
```

So the following SQL statement would be executed by your database:

```
SELECT [date],[description] FROM Table2 where date=#1/1/2000#; DELETE * FROM Table2
```

The second statement would simple delete all your data! (To be exact, the statement above would fail as MS Access does not support to chain multiple statements, but other database systems do support this, so this is a security leak that is sleeping until you migrate your database. Apart from that, there are other ways to do SQL injection in MS Access, e.g. by using Subqueries.)

By using a `PreparedStatement` you can avoid this issue. Apart from that it is more convenient to program:

```
Date date = /* java.sql.Date-object created from user input */

try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT [date],[description] FROM Table2 where date=?")
    ) {

    // set first (and only) parameter value
    stmt.setDate(1, date);

    // execute statement
    try (ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        // process result as usual
    }
}
```

Comment: > The second statement would simple delete all your data!  ... Not in Access SQL - it will cause the full statement to fail.

Comment: @Gustav You are right, statement chaining is not supported by MS Access. But other databases do, so migrating the code to another DBMS might introduce a severe security leak. For simplicity, I didn't mention that detail. But I'll update my answer. Thanks.